# Plone's MailHost queue processor thread is stopped at startup

Tags: plone

I have problems with the queue processor of the MailHost. If I enable the mail queue in the ZMI the processor thread starts inmediately, but if I restart plone the processor thread never starts itself, I must log into the ZMI and start it manually.

Since I have never used the mail queue in Plone I don't know if this is the correct behavior. If I must start the processor thread manually I think the mail queue is unusable on a production site.

Anyone there that can help me to get the processor thread started automatically on plone startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the same after startup, but after I send the first mail (using the sendto_form) the queue processor thread is listed as running.  So it looks like the queue processor thread only starts up at the moment you send the first mail.  After that, it keeps running.

This is in a Plone 4.2 that is restarted at least several times a week by memmon.  I checked, and no mails are lingering in the mail queue directory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, maurits

FTR

With your confirmation that the queue processor works I started to check the standard sendto_form and resolved the problem.

It was my mistake because I used the deprecated method "MailHost.secureSend" instead of the new "MailHost.send" method. Changing this it started the mail processor thread when the first message is send after restarting Plone.